# Is this Green Lantern and Batman reference intended for a Justice League movie?

Tags: reference, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In [Man of Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_%28film%29), there are two references to other DC character, such as:

- First Christina Wren's character called Carrie Ferris in the film resemblance to  Blake Lively's character  Carol Ferris from Green Lantern Film. Even some speculation suggest Carrie Ferris is Carol Ferris because Carol is also called as Carrie.
- Second,  In the final battle when General Zod and Superman fly into outer-space they both hit a satellite with the "Wayne Enterprise" logo. Obvious reference to Batman.

Is this intentional reference for Upcoming Justice League film or just Easter eggs? Because Justice league Movie finalization came after the success of Man of Steel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From everything I can gather about the genesis of this Justice League movie is that it has been a long and arduous project.

In 2007, the project was talked about and started slight development in order to start filming before the major writers strike. Due to this, it seems, the film was put on "indefinite hold".

Further, they attempted to get some kind of cast list together as well as "announce" plans to make a Justice League film that never came to fruition and became overshadowed by Nolan's Batman as a result due to rumors running wild and confirmation that this Batman would not be a part of the Justice League at all.

However, with the relative success of Man of Steel, and prior to that, Snyder stated that if it did do well, he would be looked to in order to put together the connected universe of this live-action Justice League.

It has also been confirmed that Nolan, Bale, and Ryan Reynolds will **not** be a part of this Justice League film at all.  Due to his involvement of producing Man of Steel it would not surprise me if Nolan had some creative input however.

What is confirmed for now is:

- DC characters do exist in the Man of Steel universe.
- David S. Goyer has been hired to write the film
- Henry Cavill will play Superman
- A different Bruce Wayne (think alternate universe) does exist in this universe.
- The actor that portrays Green Arrow on the show is in talks to try to get his character involved in this Justice League.
- Nothing has been confirmed about Green Lantern other than Ryan Reynolds declining reprising his role as Hal Jordan.
- Snyder will most likely be the front runner of this series as was Whedon to The Avengers
- Man of Steel 2 is aiming for a 2014 release.

As far as it being intentional, the knowledge that Bruce Wayne exists would lead anyone to believe that he is still the billionaire that is most known throughout Gotham City and would have something like a satellite in space.  If you notice as well there are several Lexcorp items like a truck that gets destroyed and a building with the logo on it.

I also read somewhere (I have to find it) that some of the characters of the Daily Planet were smaller known DC characters so that hardcore fans have something to look forward to and reference the fact that this is possibly the true DC universe on film, characters and all.

Sources:

[**1**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_of_Steel_%28film%29#Sequel)
[**2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_in_other_media#Film)

Comment: Green Arrow news is new for me. Now i am becoming more interested in this project. The answer is great(+1) but it doesn't addressing the point mentioned in question directly.

Comment: I think TylerShads _has_ addressed the Batman/Wayne issue pretty comprehensively. As for Christina Wren's character I'd like to point out that she is playing a Major in the movie whereas, Carol Ferris is the VP of Ferris Aircraft's in the DC universe. So this might be nothing more than a mere coincidence.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher that may be clear out in sequels.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you brought an old, answered question from the dead. Well, let me give you my input!

First and foremost, Man of Steel is the first installment in the DC Cinematic Universe. That being said, Zack Snyder confirmed that there are several tie-ins with the upcoming movies.

- The satellite was, in fact, belonging to Wayne Enterprises, which is headed by owner Bruce Wayne, played by Ben Affleck. According to several set photos from Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice, Bruce Wayne actually surveys the damage inflicted upon the planet by Superman and Zod's fatal confrontation. As such, he has since become disillusioned with Superman, which prompts his violent confrontation with his future comrade.
- Lex Luthor has already had a presence in the DC Cinematic Universe; as Superman, Zod and the debris from the Wayne Enterprises satellite crashed into Metropolis, a LexCorp building was heavily damaged. Additionally, Zod uses a LexCorp gas truck as a weapon against Superman.
- The whales that arrive near Superman were actually sent by Aquaman, who will be played by Jason Momoa. Zack Snyder has stated that he included an indirect presence to Aquaman already, so this is the only explanation, as it is the only time there is time in the sea.
- Christina Ghubril Wren's Carrie Ferris could, in fact, be one and the same. However, this has not been explicitly touched upon by Zack Snyder's party.